# Problem with solving an ordinary differential equation with integrating factor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

We have the following linear ordinary differential equation and we want to solve for `y`:

`(x-2)y' - y = 2(x-2)^3`

Can you help me find where the error is? I am getting incorrect results.

First, express the equation in the standard form of an exact differential equation:

`y + 2(x-2)^3 + (-x+2)y' = 0` where `M = y + 2(x-2)^3` and `N = -x+2`

We check if the equation is exact. It isn't, so we try to find an integrating factor `u(x)`

We find our `u(x)` and multiply our equation with it:

`uy + u2(x-2)^3 + u(-x+2)y' = 0`

Plug in `u(x) = 1/(-x+2)^2` and we get:

`1/(-x+2)^2 * y + 1/(-x+2)^2 * 2(x-2)^3 + 1/(-x+2)^2 * (-x+2)y' = 0`

Clean it up and we get:

`1/(-x+2)^2 * y + 2x - 4 + 1/(-x+2) * y' = 0`

Let's denote our potential function with F (in some materials they use the phi symbol).

`dF/dx = 1/(-x+2)^2 * y + 2x - 4`

In order to find `F`, let's integrate both sides and add `g(y)`, which represents the information that we are unable to retrieve from a partial derivative of x. Let's absorb the constant in it.

`F = (-x+2)^(-1) * y + x^2 - 4x + g(y)`

Let's find out what `g(y)` is.

`dF/dy = (-x+2)^(-1) + g'(y) = uN`

Plug in `uN` from earlier:

`dF/dy = (-x+2)^(-1) + g'(y) = (-x+2)^(-1)`

And we get `g'(y) = 0` so `g(y) = C`

Plug `g(y)` into `F`:

`F = (-x+2)^(-1) * y + x^2 - 4x + C = 0`

Solve for `y`:

`y = x^3 - 6x^2 + 8x + Cx - 2C`

This is incorrect. Where did I make a mistake?

P.S. I realize there are easier choices for `u` available, but let's not go there. I really want to find out what is wrong with this solution. Before posting this I verified that my choice for `u(x)` doesn't contain variables other than x and I confirmed that the equation with `u(x)` is exact by comparing partials derivatives. I also tried to look for blunders by verifying just about everything with Wolfram Alpha. I can't find the error.

Comment: You bring $u(x) = 1/(-x+2)^2$ from where.?

Comment: I omitted it, because I was able to confirm that the error isn't there. I used a complicated method from a textbook.

Comment: I edited OP to fix some errors I made when I was copying things from paper.

Comment: Your answer $y = x^3 - 6x^2 + 8x + Cx - 2C$ is correct. There is no mistake happens.

Comment: In the textbook they use `u = 1/(-x+2)` and arrive at `y = x^3 - 6x^2 + 12x + Cx - 8 - 2C`. I thought that you would arrive at the same solution even if you used a different `u`, as long as the constraints were fulfilled.

Comment: I checked your solution many times and no error found. Then I checked your final answer, there is no error here!

Comment: Strange. Thanks for your help!

Comment: $y=x^3-6x^2+8x+Cx-2C$ is the same as $y=x^3-6x^2+12x+cx-8-2c$ because $C=c+4$. Dont' use the same symbol for different constants.